# Handling Android preferences without magic strings

Tags: android

Im using Androids [built in way](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html) of handling preferences which works by writing all settings in an xml file. It's really nice but I can't find any good way of doing it without using magic strings in the xml and Java code.

The only way I could think of is to save the preference key as String but that doesn't feels right either. Anyone got a good way of solving this?

Comment: What is the question ? Why don't you want to use Preference screen ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear; I want to use the preference screen but I don't wanna use magic strings in my code. So I was looking for a way to store the keys in xml.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can move your "magic string" to string resources:

In you preference xml file:

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:key="@string/preferences_pdn_key"
        android:title="@string/preferences_pdn_title"
        android:summary="@string/preferences_pdn_summary"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/input_pdn_message" />
```

In your `values/strings.xml` files:

```
...
<string name="preferences_pdn_key">pdn</string>
...
```

You then can reference preference from your `Activity` or `PreferenceActivity`:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String pdnKey = getString(R.string.prefernece_pdn_key);
String pdn = sharedPreferences.getString(pdnKey, null);
```

---

If you don't like to fetch preference keys from string resources all the time you can do yet another trick:

```
public class PreferenceNames {

    /* categories */ 
    public static final String LoginCategory = MyApplication.getResourceString(R.string.preferences_login_category_key);
    ...

    /* preferences */   
    public static final String Pdn = MyApplication.getResourceString(R.string.preferences_pdn_key);
    ...
}
```

So you can now reference you preference key next way:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String pdn = sharedPreferences.getString(PreferenceNames.Pdn, null);
```

And here is how your `MyApplication` class should look like:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {    
    private static VvmApplication s_instance;

    public MyApplication(){
        s_instance = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return s_instance;
    }

    public static String getResourceString(int resId){
        return getContext().getString(resId);       
    }
}
```

Plus you need to add next thing to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:name="com.mypackage.application.MyApplication" ... >
...
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks. It would have been nice to avoid the string-xml all together to avoid problems during translation but thats a manageable problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me what are magic strings I havent heard earlier :P

Comment: Its when you write strings directly in the code. In most examples I've seen for the preference screen they have written "settingKey" in both xml and java code. I don't want to rely on having to spell the name right every time so I want to reference to the same string from both xml and java.

Comment: You can move your preference related string to a separate file, for example `preference-keys.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is [here][1]

[1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html take a look at shared preferences.

Comment: Yes thats the way I want to do it but I want to avoid the magic strings they are using in their example;  boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false); //I don't want "silentMode"